# Setting cell background from UIColor array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have an array full of UIColors. I want to set them as a cell background colour, to use as a key to replicate colour on a pie chart.

Here is this array:

```
 self.sliceColors =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [UIColor colorWithRed:246/255.0 green:155/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1],
                       [UIColor colorWithRed:129/255.0 green:195/255.0 blue:29/255.0 alpha:1],
                       [UIColor colorWithRed:62/255.0 green:173/255.0 blue:219/255.0 alpha:1],
                       [UIColor colorWithRed:229/255.0 green:66/255.0 blue:115/255.0 alpha:1],
                       [UIColor colorWithRed:148/255.0 green:141/255.0 blue:139/255.0 alpha:1],nil];
```

Thats all fine. I am trying to write the syntax to colour the cell. Having looked around, I have found this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

But I have no idea how to fill it up with the colours from the array. Everything I have tried has produced syntax errors.

Comment: What do you want this to actually look like? Do you want each cell to have one of those colors? Do you want one cell to have all of the colors? How do you want them to be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A potential solution:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   cell.backgroundColor = self.sliceColors[indexPath.row % self.sliceColors.count];
}
```